# Hyperlinks in mails not showing in gmail, but it does in Outlook

Tags: c#, email, hyperlink, gmail

I've got a c# process that send emails to customers with a hyperlink in the mail.  The mail is send from a SQL Server stored proc.  My c# program just invokes the sp.
The hyperlink works fine in Outlook, but on online gmail it only shows as text.  It is not clickable.
My mail text looks something like:

```
Hi. 
This is the hyperlink:<br>
<a href=\"serveraddress\Documents\\123_128635312685687531322.gif\">
Click Here</a><br><br>
```

What should I do to fix it?

EDIT:
My code:

```
string email = "xx@gmail.com;
string password = "MyPassword";

var credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
var msg = new MailMessage();
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

msg.From = new MailAddress(email, senderName);
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.Body = message;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

EDIT 2:
Compile message being send:

```
string message = @"Hi. <br>
This is the intro line in the mail message.<br>";

using (DataTable dtLinks = data.ExecuteDataSet(@"SELECT * 
                                                    FROM LessonFiles
                                                    WHERE Course = " + dr["Course"].ToString().DBValue() + @" AND 
                                                        Lesson = " + dr["NextLesson"].ToString().DBValue()).Tables[0])
{

int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow drLink in dtLinks.Rows)
{
    i += 1;
    message += "<a href=\"" + drLink["Link"].ToString() + "\">" + drLink["Lesson"].ToString();
    message += i == 1 ? "" : " file " + i;
    message += "</a>" + "<br>";
}
}
message += "<br>Regards<br><br>";
```

Comment: Set property IsHtml = true in MailMessage object(it's false by default, that's why gmail display message like text)

Comment: There's a property IsBodyHtml which is already set to true.  I can't see a IsHTML is c#.

Comment: And raw message please, maybe you encode it?

Comment: I added the code that compiles the message.  Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something was funny with the hyperlink itself. 
Using `http://serveraddress/Documents/logoColourBG635315550177822533.jpg` seems to work.
The original contained backslashes in the path.  The fact that it showed the hyperlink in Outlook led me to believe the address was correct.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to add target="_blank", like this...

```
message += "<a href=\"" + drLink["Link"].ToString() + "\"target=\"_blank\">" + drLink["Lesson"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Sadly not working.  Still looks fine in Outlook, but not a hyperlink when viewed in gmail (using Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

creating mail message object...

```
var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                    smtp.Timeout = 20000;

                    MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                    Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress(SenderID);
                    Msg.From = fromMail;
                    Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(TosendID));
                    Msg.Subject = subject;
                    Msg.Body = body;
```

In body add ur code.....

Hope This Helps.........